# database to store a huge tree

Tags: mysql, database, file, tree

the problem I need to solve is storing the equivalent of a file sytem tree into a database (in order to speed up search operations). The tree contains +400.000.000 inodes and for each inode I need to store some meta information (the average file path is 100 bytes, and the meta information is ~50 bytes).

Following operations will be made, from a C++ program:
1. SELECT (with expected results: ~200.000)
2. INSERT ~20.000 records at once
3. DELETE ~20.000 records at once.

Until now, I considered only relational databases: MySQL, MariaDB, PostgresSQL (I haven't done any testing so far, I'm still in "information gathering" phase) and I read some documentation about storing trees in such a DB.

**First option**
- The Adjacency List Model: each item in the table contains a pointer to its parent.
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

**Second option**
- store all directories in a separate table
- have a separate table for rest of the files, with pointers to the directory they belong to

so the tables will look like this:
DirTable:

```
/home  
/home/test/
```

FileTable:

```
file1
file2
```

My questions:
1. do you know another model suitable for storing a huge tree in a relational database?
2. if I'd search for a NoSQL DB, where should I start?

Many thanks.

Comment: You could look into hierarchical databases, such as LDAP (OpenDS, OpenDJ, OpenLDAP). What kind of search operations do you want to optimize? E.g. searching for a file with a given name anywhere in the tree and searching files with a set of attributes restricted to a subtrees are best served by slightly different data organization.

Comment: Hi Joni. Because we're gonna do a lot of searches for single files (from a subtree) per operation, we think it's better to load all files from a subtree in memory (let's say, 200.000 entries), reduce the memory footprint as possible and then do all look-ups in memory. Otherwise (single select for every file) will be too inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are best served by a  structure that can give you an entire subtree with a single select. There are a few of ways to achieve this, each with its benefits and drawbacks:

- In nested sets you add two columns to the tables: lft and rgt. The subtree of a node has its lft and rgt values values between the lft and rgt values of the node. This model is simple to query but changes to the tree require rewriting the lft and rgt values of the entire tree, so updates can be expensive.
- Path enumeration would maintain the absolute path of a file in a column. This model is also simple to query, but the fact that you can only index a fixed-length prefix of the path limits the depth of trees that can be efficiently searched.
- For closure table you would add a new table that, for every directory on the system, holds the ids of the files that are contained somewhere in the subtree. Again, simple to query, but the closure table can grow fairly big and has to be updated if a directory is moved.

This slideshow explains these models with graphs and sample code: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data